# Writing code to generate two circles in sklearn with radius r1=2 and r2=5 with centres located at (5,3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

How to add radius r1=2 for circle 1 with class 0 and radius r2=5 for circle 2 with class 1 for the code with centres at (5,3)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
# generate 2d classification dataset
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=500,noise= 0.08)
r = np.random.ranf() * 5 + 5
# scatter plot, dots colored by class value
df = DataFrame(dict(x=X[:,0], y=X[:,1], label=y))
colors = {0:'yellow', 1:'purple'}
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
grouped = df.groupby('label')
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', label=key, color=colors[key])
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing your code just a little bit, the circles you want can be created.

There are only 2 changes to your code:

```py
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=500,noise= 0.08,factor=0.4)
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```py
df = DataFrame(dict(x=X[:,0]*5+5, y=X[:,1]*5+3, label=y^1))
                            ^^^^          ^^^^         ^^
```

Here's the full listing with a few comments:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
# generate 2d classification dataset
# Use `factor` to specify a ratio of radii
# Here 2/5 = 0.4
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=500,noise= 0.08,factor=0.4)
# `r` isn't used here
# r = np.random.ranf() * 5 + 5
# scatter plot, dots colored by class value
# `x` and `y` are scaled (*5) and translated (+5,+3),
# classes/labels are swapped here per your specification
df = DataFrame(dict(x=X[:,0]*5+5, y=X[:,1]*5+3, label=y^1))
colors = {0:'yellow', 1:'purple'}
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
grouped = df.groupby('label')
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', label=key, color=colors[key])
pyplot.show()
```